# Separating dictionaries within a list with new line

Tags: python

How do I separate multiple dictionaries within a list with a new line.

e.g.

```
[{'qns': '1 + 3 + 3', 'ans': 7}, {'qns': '2 - 5 - -1', 'ans': -2}, {'qns': '3 x 2', 'ans': 6}, {'qns': '12 / 3 / 2', 'ans': 2.0}, {'qns': '0 x 23', 'ans': 0}, {'qns': '1 + 2 + 3', 'ans': 6}]
```

to

```
[{'qns': '1 + 3 + 3', 'ans': 7}, 
{'qns': '2 - 5 - -1', 'ans': -2}, 
{'qns': '3 x 2', 'ans': 6}, 
{'qns': '12 / 3 / 2', 'ans': 2.0}, 
{'qns': '0 x 23', 'ans': 0}, 
{'qns': '1 + 2 + 3', 'ans': 6}]
```

Heres my code:

```
new_list = []
qnsans = {
            "qns" : str_math,
            "ans" : math
        }

new_list.append(qnsans)
return print(new_list)
```

Comment: Use the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) module.

Comment: Is there a way for me to do it without having to use pprint?

Comment: You can write your own loop

Comment: Why are you returning the value of `print`? It doesn't return anything.

Comment: [What are you trying to do exactly ?](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont why would you want to append a new line unless you are writting it to a file. So if that is what you are trying to do,here is how you can do it:

```
with open("sample.txt", "a") as a_file:
  
  for newline in list:
     a_file.write(new_line)
     a_file.write("\n")
```

Comment: This will print a literal `'\n'` between the list elements, it won't put them on their own lines.

Comment: @Barmar I got the point.i have made suitable changes to my answer

Answer (score -1):

```
list1=[{'qns': '1 + 3 +....'}]
for item in list1:
    print(item,"\n")
```

Comment: What is the list comprehension for? You'll just create a list full of `None`

Comment: More generally, list comprehensions are for creating data, not causing side effects. At least, that's the sensible way to think about them.

Comment: Answer's are great. But for best practices, please provide an explanation. You only posting code makes the OP and future commers copy and paste your answer without understanding the logic behind the answer. Please provide an answer with some explanation. Thank You!